# How to enable or install XLST in php xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I have a default installation of xampp which has php 5.3. I came    across an issue while using symfony framework CLI to create database    tables. I am using Windows XP. Here is the command I run:

```
 symfony propel:build-sql 
 Output: Could not perform XLST transformation.Make    sure php has been compiled/configured to support XLST.
```

Please guide me through the installation of XLST in windows xp.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably need to enable the [XSL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php).

Look for something like the following in your `php.ini` file

```
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

and un-comment it by removing the semi-colon. You may need to check the location of the extension and that it complies with your [`extension_dir` directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir).

Comment: For me (PHP v7.2) it was just `;extension=xsl`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Phil's answer...

I found that the easiest way to find and enable the `XSL extension` was through the **XAMPP Control Panel** UI.

1. Open the **XAMPP Control Panel**
2. In "Actions" click on "Config" next to "Apache" module and click on **PHP (php.ini)**.
   [image: XAMPP Control Panel PHP (php.ini)]
3. That should open the PHP.ini file in text editor. Search for "`;extension=php_xsl.dll`" and remove "`;`" from the line.
4. Save the file and close.
5. Restart Apache.